# How to share the same MVC3 View in 2 different websites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am creating an **MVC3 web application**. It has an Administrator side and a Client Side. They will be hosted on SEPERATE servers. The client side will be **available ONLIE via internet** and the Admin will be an **INTRANET application**. There are **certain views which will be used by both  the the public and the admin areas**. Where should I put them. Do I have to create **2 copies** of the views in both applications or should **I put it somewhere common** and share it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definetly can give you a good start point.

http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/